# Should the following FB:Share code with meta title and descrition work?

Tags: facebook, fbml, share

```
<fb:share-button class="meta" type="box_count">
    <meta name="title" content="A sample title"/>
    <meta name="description" content="A sample title"/>
    <link rel="image_src" href="path_to_img" />
    <link rel="target_url" href="a sample url"/>
</fb:share-button>
```

The above code displays the number of shares (or likes) and indeed shares the link on FB, but it does not make use of the meta title or description. I would like to push the title/description to Facebook.  Is it possible and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Update : ultimately, i would like to use the share functionality as 'i support cause X'. So when a user clicks the share button, it offers to send to that user's feed: I supported cause x on www.site.com. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Put the title and description in  of the page you are sharing as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/):

```
<head> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="HeartBooth"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="HeartBooth gallery"/>
...
```

Comment: Id like to be able to set title and desc on each page load and not rely meta tags in the head